# Using the TinyLAF

Tags: java, user-interface

Where can I find information on how to create a UI with Tiny?

Or maybe somebody know another tool instead swing which can help me create UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described here [on the oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
        // Set L&F 
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        new TinyLookAndFeel());
} catch (Exception e) {
   // handle exception
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}

new SwingApplication(); //Create and show the GUI.
```

}